# Conditionals in dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

Is it possible to do the following

```
docker build --build-arg myvar=yes
```

f

```
RUN if ["$myvar" == "yes"]; \
    then FROM openjdk \
          COPY . . \
          RUN java -jar myjarfile.jar \
    fi
```

As you can tell from above i only want to run the specific section in the dockerfile if the build argument is set. I've seen similar thread but they seems to always be running bash commands. If its possible i can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, doing conditional execution in Dockerfiles without the help of the shell is severely limited, see https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae

The idea behind existing approaches is to use a Docker multistage build and create different stages for the different outcomes of the `IF`. Then, at one point, a stage to copy data from is selected based on the value of a variable.

This is an example similar to what you wrote:

```
# docker build -t test --build-arg MYVAR=yes .
# docker build -t test --build-arg MYVAR=no .

ARG MYVAR=no

FROM openjdk:latest as myvar-yes
COPY . /datadir
RUN java -jar /datadir/myjarfile.jar || true

FROM openjdk:latest as myvar-no
RUN mkdir /datadir

FROM myvar-${MYVAR} as myvar-src

FROM debian:10
COPY --from=myvar-src /datadir/ /
RUN ls /
```

Stage `myvar-no` is a variant with an empty `/datadir`. Stage `myvar-yes` contains the jarfile and runs it once (remove the `|| true` for actual use, it is just that I did not provide a "real" jarfile in my local tests). Then the last stage copies from the stage `myvar-${MYVAR}` and invokes `ls` to be able to see the differences between the two variants.

I have not understand all of the question about syntax: If there are some troubles with getting the bash syntax correctly, that is possibly easier than trying to conditionally run Dockerfile statements.